# How to properly configure sudoers file, on debian wheezy?

Tags: sudo, root, non-root-user, debian

I have seen many blog posts that say, it is enough to do

```
aptitude install sudo
su root
adduser USERNAME sudo
```

But that only protects `aptitude`, in other words:

- `aptitude install sendmail` will ask for password, you need to be
  `sudo` to run `aptitude`
- `apt-get install sendmail` won't ask for password, no `sudo` privileges
  needed
- If you edit protected files, like files in `etc` it won't ask for
  password, no `sudo` privileges needed
- You can run and stop services like `apache`, it won't ask for
  password, no `sudo` privileges needed

How to fix this? This is my sudoers file:

```
 This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
```

This is the output of `sudo -l`:

```
Matching Defaults entries for root on this host:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User root may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Comment: After `su root`, you're logged in as the `root` user, so you have full access to everything.  To get back to being a regular use who has to use `sudo` for privileged operations, logout of the shell running as `root`.

Comment: I am new in Linux but Debian wiki says - adduser username sudo https://wiki.debian.org/sudo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You haven't added any sudo rule, so you can't use sudo for anything.

The command `adduser USERNAME sudo` adds the specified user to the group called `sudo`. A group with that name must exist; create it with `addgroup sudo` if it doesn't. After adding the user to the group, the user must log out and back in for the group membership to take effect.

`sudo` is not a special group name. It's a convention to allow users in the group called `sudo` to run commands as root via the `sudo` utility. This requires the following line in the `sudoers` file:

```
%sudo ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Run `visudo` to edit the sudoers file, never edit it directly.

I have no idea why you believe that “that only protects aptitude”. There is nothing special about aptitude. Once you've authorized a user to run commands as root, that user can run `sudo aptitude …` or `sudo apt-get …` or `sudo service …`, or `sudoedit` to edit files that require root permission to edit. Being in the sudoers file doesn't directly change the privileges of your user, what it does is that it allows you to run `sudo` to run commands as root. Commands run as root only when you run them through `sudo`. Some programs may do that automatically, especially GUI programs where the user interface runs without special privileges and only the backend runs as root, but commands executed as root are always executed by `sudo`.

Comment: He has run `sudo -l` as root. Even if there are useful definitions for users they would not have been shown. Thus your guess "You haven't added any sudo rule" may be wrong.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I don't understand your comment. “You haven't added any sudo rule” isn't a guess: the `sudoers` file is in the question.

Comment: I was close to getting depressed, realizing that I was too focussed on the `sudo -l` output but luckily... It seems that the question content cannot be the whole file because it is not consistent with the output. At least my `sudo` version does **not** claim "User root may run the following commands" with a `sudoers` without any command definition (like the one in the question).

Comment: @HaukeLaging You're right, I checked with wheezy and indeed `sudo -l` just says “User root is not allowed to run sudo on darkstar.”. And the `sudo` group is in the sudoers file by default on wheezy. The requisite entries may have been moved into a file under `/etc/sudoers.d`. In any case, whatever the sudoers file contains, it wouldn't do what Fischer assumes.

Answer (score 5):

What *may* have happened is: sudo is caching your password. So, after you've correctly completed the implementation of sudo on your system, you have to enter the password for the *first* command, and after that it's cached for some time. If that happens and you run the sequence

```
sudo aptitude install sendmail
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Then you'll have to provide a password on the first command, but not on the second (at least while you are still within the timeout). This may *feel* like it's protecting only the first command, but not the second. Without further information (complete shell transcripts), there's no way to tell...

Comment: Yes. The one doesn't exclude the other. The correct answer does nicely explain how to set up sudo correctly, and in that sense, it answers the question. It does not explain why, in the words of the question, "that only protects aptitude". Gilles writes himself: "I have no idea why you believe that “that only protects aptitude”". As I said, to really understand that phenomenon, more information is necessary. I think a downvote is a bit harsh given that my answer is factually correct, addresses the original question and fills a gap in the existing answer.

Comment: Good idea, this may be the source of Fischer's confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the above answer, you are going in the right way. At least in my Debian Jessie, i made a soft link to /usr/bin of the command in the path /sbin. For example: /sbin/ifup, i put a soft link (ln -s) to /usr/bin of it and i can use it.

Another important thing is to put NOPASSWD like this:

```
User_Alias NET = goviedo
Cmnd_Alias ETH = /sbin/ifup
NET ALL = NOPASSWD:ETH
```