# Can't add sudo privilleges to a user

Tags: debian, sudo

This is my first time with Debian and I don't really understand how to grant myself sudo access. I have a fresh install with a root password and a normal default user. I just want my normal default user to have sudo privilliges. So far I have done the following.

```
su
!entered password
apt-get install sudo
adduser [normal_default_user] sudo
```

It accepted the command but I still can't get access to sudo. I am already a bit confused, can someone explain how I can do what I'm trying to do please? I've seen people talk about using visudo, but the man page for it doesn't describe how to add a user to sudo, so I need your help.

Comment: Did you log out and back in? Group changes (which is what `adduser` does, it added the specified user to the group called `sudo) take effect when you log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regular username is john:

```
$ su -
# apt-get install sudo
# usermod -a -G sudo john
# logout
$ logout
```

`$` indicates a command executed as a regular user.

`#` indicates a command executed as the user, *root*.

Log in again as *john* and execute `sudo -i` to test.

Comment: Ok thanks Christopher. I will test this in a second. Can I ask what I've done using the last command in my post? I just need to work out if I need to undo that?

Comment: Thanks again. Can I ask you 1 more question since I'm learning how to use man pages. I just did a man usermod to try and work out what you did. -a means append, but I only see a -g (lower case) option. How am I normally supposed to find out how to use the G command there?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't logout though. It said I need to use "exit" twice. So I did that, and it still didn't work. But when I rebooted it worked. Do you know why? Sorry I can't tick or up vote you answer, I have not enough reputation on this forum.

Comment: I tested this just now, it does not work.

Comment: @Christopher I just fresh installed Debian in a VM and it doesn't work. Baazigar's answer worked.

Comment: @Christopher no this is the exact question I wanted an answer for, and your answer does not work in the current version of Debian.

Comment: Contrary to confused, down-voting, "does-not-work" naysayers, since at least 2015 until today, the default group in Debian for using `sudo` is still named `sudo`. The answer works just fine when you need to install sudo or when you need to group a user in the `sudo` group. One must remember to logout and back in again to pick up the group membership, of course.

Comment: Worked for me, at least gave me the idea that I just needed to logout and log back in.  Instead of `su -` I ran `su root` and instead of `logout` I used `exit`. But yeah, once I logged out and logged back in, I had sudo access on Debian 11.2, the latest version.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also just create your user as normal, then login as root and add this in /etc/sudoers:

youruser    ALL=(ALL)   ALL

This says youruser can sudo and run any command as root without being prompted for a password on each command.

If you look at /etc/sudoers after running the command posted by Christopher, you will probably find that command created a line similar to the above.

Comment: It's not possible for me to edit that file. Also, I don't want to run everything as root.  Chris's command doesn't work by the way. It doesn't accept the usermod command

Comment: Oh he's modified it to say -G, so now it works :)

Comment: As far as I know, you are not going to be able to just add yourself sudo. The system admin will have to add it for you. It is for 'privileged' users, so not everyone can just assume the ability for themselves.

Comment: Hilarious, since I'm the admin

Comment: If you are the admin, why can't you edit /etc/sudoers??

Comment: In short, /etc/sudoers file says who can sudo or not. You can use a command line tool to affect this file, or do it yourself. You can set it to allow all commands or only some commands to be run as root, and whether to use a password or not.

Comment: I read it on the internet that you need to use visudo or something, and I don't understand it

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86748/how-to-properly-configure-sudoers-file-on-debian-wheezy

Comment: Yes I already have read this document. The problem is he shows his file, but doesn't explain it. So as a beginner, I am non the wiser. It is also where I found the command that didn't work in my initial post

Comment: I tried this and it worked, unlike the accepted answer which seems to be out of date.